# Knockout js: unable to open a mailto page from a link in databind inside a foreach databind click event

Tags: knockout.js, viewmodel

I have a list of messages where I bind the template of these message into a click event then inside of this template I have a hyperlink bind to js function that should open a mailto page.

But clicking this link doesn't open the page although the js function executes and if I right click "go to this address" it works. I tried many KO methods as "clickBubble: false" the "controlsDescendantBindings" flag set to true, "e.stopImmediatePropagation()". But all failed!

Here is a part of my code:

(the Partial View)

```
<div data-bind="template: { name: 'messageTemplate', foreach: OldMessageCollection}">
...    
</div>
```

(the template: messageTemplate)

```
<div class="message_listed" data-bind="click: $root.GetSelectedMessage">
...
<ul class="actions_list">
<li><a data-bind="attr: { href: $root.mailToLink(ReplyTo())}"></a></li>
...
</ul>
</div>
```

ReplyTo() is an observable in KO and OldMessageCollection is observableArray.

Comment: Can you show us your view model? Specifically, the `mailToLink` function snippet?

Comment: it is solved using '<a data-bind="attr: { href: $root.mailToLink()}, click: function() {return true;}, clickBubble: false">ReplyTo</a>'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it is solved using

```
<a data-bind="attr: { href: $root.mailToLink()}, click: function() {return true;}, clickBubble: false">ReplyTo</a>
```

Comment: Just curious, how does 'return true' in the click handler impact the code?

Comment: Look at the documentation in knockout of the click event handler. Note 3 says: "However, if you do want to let the default click action proceed, just return true from your click handler function." See for more info: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html